# PYD file not found

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed Python 3.7 on my system and I am running one simple python file in which imports a `.pyd` file. When running the script I got error like:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "demoTemp\run.py", line 1, in 
>         from pyddemo import fun
>         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyddemo'

pyddemo is pyd file.

Is there any dependency for pyd file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of my problem its just mismatch of python version in which I have created pyd and python version in which I am using it.